# Suggestion field doesn't work properly - AS3 AIR code

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I've got a suggestion field in my app. The code was, so far, working (or I thought it was).
It's link to a txt file. Each sentences in the text file are seperate by a #;

Example :

Hi#How are you?#Good job#

I've got 175 sentences.

Weirdly, if I enter "N" for "Non",the code is working and suggest me every sentences with the letter N

[Every sentences with "N" is suggested](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kendd.png)

But if I, then, enter "No", the sentence "Non" isn't suggested anymore !

["Non" is not here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fp31Q.png)

And it does that with a lot of sentences....

Here's my code :

```
function checkKeypress(event: KeyboardEvent): void {
                    if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.BACK) {
                    trace("back pushed");
                            for (var l:int = 0; l < textfields.length; l++)
                {
                    removeChild(textfields[l]);
                }
                suggested = [];
                textfields = [];
                currentSelection = 0;
    }
}
    
         function loadComplete(e:Event):void
        {
            if(drehuLang ==true){
            suggestions = e.target.data.split("#");
            }else{
            suggestions = e.target.data.split(","); 
            }
        }

         function suggest(e:KeyboardEvent):void
        {


            suggested = [];

            for (var i:int = 0; i < textfields.length; i++)
            {
                removeChild(textfields[i]);
            }

            textfields = [];

            for (var j:int = 0; j < suggestions.length; j++)
            {
                    if (suggestions[j].indexOf(inputField.text.toLowerCase()) != -1)  
                {
                    var term:TextField = new TextField();
                    term.width = 360;
                    term.height = 24;
                    term.x = 18;
                    term.y = (24 * suggested.length) + 83;
                    term.border = true;
                    term.borderColor = 0x353535;
                    term.background = true;
                    term.backgroundColor = 0xFF9900;
                    term.textColor = 0x4C311D;
                    term.defaultTextFormat = format;

                    term.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, useWord);
                    term.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, hover);
                    term.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, out);
                    term.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, tellMe);

                    addChild(term);
                    textfields.push(term);

                    suggested.push(suggestions[j]);

                    term.text = suggestions[j];
                }
                
            }

            if (inputField.length == 0)
            {
                suggested = [];

                for (var k:int = 0; k < textfields.length; k++)
                {
                    removeChild(textfields[k]);
                }

                textfields = [];
            }

            if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN && currentSelection < textfields.length-1)
            {
                currentSelection++;
                textfields[currentSelection].textColor = 0x4C311D;
            }
            
            if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.UP && currentSelection > 0)
            {
                currentSelection--;
                textfields[currentSelection].textColor = 0x4C311D;
            }
            
            if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.ENTER)
            {
                inputField.text = textfields[currentSelection].text;
                
                suggested = [];

                for (var l:int = 0; l < textfields.length; l++)
                {
                    removeChild(textfields[l]);
                }

                textfields = [];
                currentSelection = 0;
            }

        }
```

Any idea what could be the problem ?

Answer (score 4):

You did not normalize `suggestions` to lowercase while checking if lowercased input is present in each suggestions. So, "Non" reacts on the ending "n" when selecting first time, but "Non" does not contain "no" so it doesn't show up in the second case. So, create `suggestions_lower` array, fill it with lowercased suggestions, then check against that while filling textfields with original suggestions.